# Order MySQL result by column value

Tags: php, mysql, grouping

I'm sorry if this is bad being my 2nd post today, but I need a little help one more time.
I have table in mysql DB which holds some products( id, name, description, price, url, CATEGORY ). Now, when I display the products, I need to first display all products having category='X' ( regardless of the actual order of the products in the table ), than the products with category="Y" and finally the products with category="Z". Having only 3 categories, I just added the column to the products table, without creating a separate 'category' table (I know it's bad).
This is the simple code to pull out all the products(I can't use PDO due to the fact the website is old and done only with old/regular mysql)

```
while($prod = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)) {
    $id = $prod['id'];
    $titolo = $prod['titolo'];
    $descr = $prod['descrizione'];
    $prezzo = $prod['prezzo'];
    $foto_piccola = $prod['url_foto_piccola'];
    $foto_grande = $prod['url_foto_grande'];
    $cat = $prod['categoria'];
            // display all products
}
```

So any ideas how can I do this easy/fast ? My first guess was to make a switch('category') inside the while() loop, but I end up with a lot of duplicate code.

Any help and suggestions are very appreciated,
Thank you

This is my $sql `$sql = mysql_query(" SELECT * FROM prodotti Order BY categoria='marmellata' DESC, categoria='altro' DESC, categoria='oli' DESC")`

Bit this way doesn't work. I want to pull the name of the category and below it display the products of that category

Comment: Why don't you make the MySQL give it to you sorted already?

Comment: Can you provide an example output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do `Order By category` if your category field is an INT and your categories are entered in the order you want.

-OR-

You can do `Order BY category='X' DESC, category='Y' DESC, category='Z' DESC` if your categories are entered by name (although I would suggest entering them by ID)

Comment: Basically I want something like this: Beverages: ( display all products with category Beverages ), Food: ( same thing.. ), Others: ( same thing..). Where Beverages, Food and Others are <h2> and below them the products displayed

Comment: Can you post an example of the output of your Query? I will be easier to help you.

Comment: My query SELECT * From the table, pretty simple and common. I can't understand what output of the query means ?

Comment: Sorry, output may not be the best word (I'm french speaking). What I meant was 'result'. I'd like to see an example of the result of your query.

Comment: http://www.lapalombella.it/prodotti.php this is basically it. Don't mind the style, just the products being displayed

Comment: Another thing you could do: get all your categories from the database, and then, with a for loop, you get your products related to that category

Answer (score 1):

You can even use Field() function of SQL

```
order by Field(category, X, Y, Z)
```